# How would you compute the rank of a node in a Splay tree, if the rank is that Node's inorder traversal position?

Tags: algorithm, nodes

The rank is the inorder traversal position of the node, starting at 1. Each node has a subtree size variable, that is equal to the total number of nodes attached below this node + 1 (the node itself is included). So if the root had 2 children, and each of those children had one child, the root would return a size of 5.

I know that the rank of the root could be calculated by taking the size of its left subtree, and adding 1. But what about the the rank of the left subtrees right child, for instance? I can't think of any particular, catchall way to determine the rank of a node.

I'm trying to implement a splay tree, and knowing the rank of a node is crucial to many of the operations.

Comment: Does it not suffice to splay the node in question and apply the root formula?

Comment: I actually figured it out. After the root, every time you go left, the rank of that node will be the rank of the previous node - 1, minus the size of that node's right subtree. And every time you go down, the rank of that node will be the rank of the previous node + 1, plus the size of that nodes left subtree.